# How to create a `context.Provider`/`context.Consumer`-like structure to pass values in a bot app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, botframework, bots

I'm trying to pass a property, that is inside the first position of an array of objects, to another module so I can use this value later. I've tried to pass it as module(args), but it keeps reading the default value which is 0. Is there a way to do this?

I tried to implement some `React.context` but the Bot framework Emulator is refusing it.

```
/////////////////Module that ll acquire the value/////////////////////////////
    getCard(bot, builder, params) {
        let configValues = { ...params[0] }

        bot.dialog(`${configValues.path}`, function (session) {
            var msg = new builder.Message(session);

            const cardItem = (obj) => {
                return (new builder.HeroCard(session)
                    .title(`${obj.title}`)
                    .text(`R$ ${obj.price}`)
                    .images([builder.CardImage.create(session, `${obj.img}`)])
                    .buttons([
                        builder.CardAction.imBack(session, `${obj.price} Item adicionado!`, 'add to cart')
                        // !onClick event must add the current obj.price to 
                        // the configValues.total(Ex: configValues.total += obj.price)!
                    ])
                )
            }
            msg.attachmentLayout(builder.AttachmentLayout.carousel)
            msg.attachments(
                eval(params.map(obj => cardItem(obj)))
            );
            //!in here before end the dialog is where i want to update
// the configValues.total so i can show it in the -> Checkout module
            session.send(msg).endDialog()
        }).triggerAction({ matches: configValues.regex });
    }
}
//////////////CheckOut.Module///////////////////////////////
{...}
let configValues = { ...params[0] }
    let state = {
        nome: "",
        endereco: "",
        pagamento: "",
        total: configValues.total // this is the value to be read
    }

    bot.dialog('/intent', [
        {...},
        (session, results) => {
            state.pagamento = results.response
            session.send(
                JSON.stringify(state) // here is the place to be printed
            )
        {...}   
    ]
    ).triggerAction({ matches: /^(finalizar|checar|encerrar|confirmar pedido|terminar)/i })
```

Comment: Can you clarify what's going on?Where is the default value being set? Where is the error occuring? What error is the Emulator giving?

Comment: The more of your code that you can share, the better. I can't really see how your CheckOut Module is being called or how most of the code interacts together.

Comment: i've solved part of the problem with a quite different strategy, Now the value is indeed passing but in other to do that i had to create another bot.dialog() based on a match fired by a postBack() in which this one ll store the given value catched by results.response on the bot.dialog() and push it into an array of prices, and then i calculate the total from a single cardBox, but the new problem is to sum the total from all the CardBox that were clicked  [GitHub] (http://github.com/VyTorBrB/botTalk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you solved your original problem, I'll answer the one in your comment.

Your problem is here:

```js
cartId.map((obj, i , arr) => {
            // if (!obj.total) {
            //     obj.total.reduce(i => i += i)
            // }
            const newtotal = new total
            newtotal.getTotals(bot, builder, obj, arr)
        })
```

`cartId` contains the totals for each of your items. When you call `map` on it, you're passing each item individually to `getTotals`, which passes each item to `checkout()`

The reason you can't sum all of the totals and can only sum one item's total is that you pass `cartId` to `checkout` and `cartId` has been changed to just a single item. Instead, there's a couple of different things you could do:

1. Pass the whole `cartId` from `cartItems` and use something like `for (var key in cartItems)` in `totalConstructor()` and `checkoutConstructor()`. This is probably the easiest, but not very memory efficient.
2. Use [BotBuilder's State Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-concepts?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#saving-state) to store your `totals` array in `userData`, then sum that at the end. This might be more difficult to implement, but would be a much better route to go. [Here's a sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/v3-sdk-samples/Node/core-State) that can help you get started.